# Comparing Language Model of two corpora

Tags: neural-network, lstm, rnn, sequence-to-sequence, language-model

I know using Conditional Language Model I can learn the probability of a sentence given the corpus I used to train my model. I will then be able to generate meaningful text by sampling from the distribution of sentences.

Now what I want to do is to compare the text generated from the language model of two different corpora on the same topic.

Use case: I want to compare the headline that a right winning vs left winning news outlet would use for a given news content. (my training data would be a large set of headline+news content from both news outlet)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly (please comment if I don't), you want to compare the output text from two different language models. Therefore, I don't think you should worry too much about the language models themselves.

If I was you, I'd probably do a simple TFIDF analysis so that you can gain a better understanding of what terms are more prevalent in certain news outlets.

Take a look at [scattertext](https://spacy.io/universe/project/scattertext), it allows you to create visualizations like the following:

[image]

Comment: Thank you this is great. And I presumably can do something with structural topic modeling and use the ideology as the covariate too. However, I wanted to do something more sophisticated in terms of learning the style and interaction/squence of words across two media outlet. That is, both new outlet may use similar words in their headlines about a topic yet with difference in style.